# How to convert bytes into image

Tags: asp.net

I am generating a report using Telerik and displaying it as PDF in UI. Can anyone tell me, how to display that report as an image in UI using jquery and asp.net mvc3

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethig like this:-

```
 public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray1)
 {
  MemoryStream m1= new MemoryStream(byteArray1);
  Image i1= Image.FromStream(m1);
  return i1;
 }
```

Check out this link:- [ByteToImage](http://forums.asp.net/t/1718234.aspx/1)